# Mostrar datos de una consulta con ASP a mysql

Tags: mysql, asp.net, datagrid, sql

Hola he estado dandole la vuelta muchas veces a esta idea pero no logro que el datagrid se llene con la consulta a la DB mysql
reitero estoy usando asp.net y mysql

```
LA SOLUCION FUE ALGO DIFERENTE

protected void buscar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MySqlConnection conect = new MySqlConnection("Server = 127.0.0.1; database = CENTRAL_PACIENTES; Uid=root; pwd=12345678;");
            conect.Open();

            MySqlCommand consulta = new MySqlCommand();
            consulta.CommandText = ("select * from PACIENTES where id_pac = '" + buscar_pac.Text + "';");
            consulta.Connection = conect;

            using (MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter())
            {
                consulta.Connection = conect;
                da.SelectCommand = consulta;
                using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                {
                    da.Fill(dt);
                    dtagrid_consult.DataSource = dt;
                    dtagrid_consult.DataBind();
                }
            }    
            conect.Close();

        }
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el error que te aparece?

Comment: esta es la solución la encontré y decidí compartirla

Comment: En la parte inferior hay una caja de texto para colocar la respuesta. Edita la pregunta dejándola solo como pregunta y usa la ubicación antes mencionada para colocar la respuesta :)